# Detect click in gutter (left margin) of TDbGrid?

Tags: delphi

I have a descendant of a TDBGrid that allows multiple rows to be selected.

I'd like to turn this mode on when they click in the gutter, and off when they click in any cell in the grid.

Is there a way in in the OnMouseDown event handler I can detect where they're clicking?

Comment: It's difficult in `OnMouseDown`; you can get the coordinates, but then you have to track down the column under those coordinates and see if it's the right one. However, the `TDBGrid.OnCellClick` should work instead. You can also look at `OnColEner`.

Comment: Testing that here: OnCellClick (as the name implies) only fires on cell clicks, so that's 1/2 my need. It can turn multi-select off.

But, I still need a way to detect if they click in the gutter, so I can turn it on. I simply need to know if they're clicking to the left of column 0's left border.

Comment: OnCellClick won't work; it doesn't fire on the gutter. OnMouseDown will work, but it only seems to fire on the title row (including the gutter), and you have to do some work to retrieve the actual cell clicked on. I think you're better off just using the standard keys for multi-select - `Ctrl+Click` and `Shift+Click` - just like every other app in Windows does. :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Ken. +1 for effort and helpfulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnMouseDown` is difficult; you can get the coordinates via the `X` and `Y` parameters to the event, and convert to a row and column by typecasting the `TDBGrid` to it's ancestor `TCustomGrid`:

```
var
  Coord: TGridCoord;
begin
  Coord := TCustomGrid(DBGrid1).MouseCoord(X, Y);
  if Coord.X = 0 then
    // We're in the "gutter"
end;
```

However, it seems that `OnMouseDown` only fires for `TDBGrid` when the header row is clicked.

`OnCellClick` seems like a possible alternative, but it only fires on actual cells (excluding the gutter and header row), so it won't work. Neither will `OnColEnter`, as it doesn't fire when you'd want it to either.

It looks like your best option would be to use the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifiers with the left mouse button to do your multiple selections, like every other app in Windows that does multi-select.